# Why "IF NOT EXISTS" doesn't work in Maintenance plan?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

My maintenance plan contains these T-SQL instructions:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='_Document415_Fld13294_Fld13301' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('my_db.dbo._Document415')
) BEGIN 

create index [_Document415_Fld13294_Fld13301] on my_db.[dbo].[_Document415] ([_Fld13294RRef],[_Fld13301RRef])


END
```

but I get this error:

> Index [_Document415_Fld13294_Fld13301] already exists

It looks like `IF NOT EXISTS` does not work when used in a Maintenance plan (because in simple query it works just fine - no errors).

Answer (score 1):

That exact batch should error everywhere. Don't consider just *part* of the batch (e.g. `IF NOT EXISTS` in isolation.

Why does it error? Because the error you're seeing is a *compilation* error.

Why does a runtime check not protect you from a compilation error? For the same reason it won't help in most languages<sup>1</sup>. Compilation comes before execution.

You need to prevent the inner statement from being compiled until after the runtime check has completed. This is most easily done by moving it into an `EXEC sp_executesql`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='_Document415_Fld13294_Fld13301' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('my_db.dbo._Document415')
)
BEGIN 
    EXEC sp_executesql N'create index [_Document415_Fld13294_Fld13301] on my_db.[dbo].[_Document415] ([_Fld13294RRef],[_Fld13301RRef])'
END
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming the language is being used with a compiler and compilation doesn't happen at the statement level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have no experiense with compiled languages (as you can see). :(  And, unfortunately, had no luck with `EXEC sp_executesql`. Got the same error after modifying T-SQL instruction as you suggested.

Comment: Am I missing something else?